# How to draw overlapped ractangles with some positioning in flutter?

Tags: flutter

> **I want to draw multiple rectangles like this**
>  [image]

I have used `CustomPainter` to get desired result but getting something different.

I have shared the code and undesired output image below, 
Please help me to draw the overlapped ractangles with some positioning to get desired output.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    // double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: _width,
        // height: _height,
        child: Center(
          child: Stack(children: <Widget>[
            CustomPaint(
              painter: DrawCustomRect(0, 0, 80, 112, 0xFFFA2A2A),
            ),
            CustomPaint(
              painter: DrawCustomRect(0, 0, 16, 96, 0xFFFF5454),
            ),
            CustomPaint(
              //  DrawCustomRect(_left,_top,_right, _bottom, _color);
              painter: DrawCustomRect(0, 0, 16, 80, 0xFFFF8D8D),
            ),

          ]),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawCustomRect extends CustomPainter {
  final double _left;
  final double _top;
  final double _right; //width
  final double _bottom; //height
  final int _color;

  DrawCustomRect(this._left, this._top, this._right, this._bottom, this._color);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(
      new Rect.fromLTRB(this._left, this._top, this._right, _bottom),
      new Paint()..color = new Color(_color),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawCustomRect oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image: this is output of below code]

Comment: I've edited my answer to include both the approaches, container stack and custom painter. You may take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches to it. The first and easy one is to use a combination of stack and container widget to achieve the above effect. Here's the code I used

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Stack(
          children: <Widget>[
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0.4, 0.1),
              child: Container(
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
                color: Colors.red[200],
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0.3, 0.1),
              child: Container(
                width: 70,
                height: 70,
                color: Colors.red[300],
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0.2, 0.1),
              child: Container(
                width: 80,
                height: 80,
                color: Colors.red[400],
              ),
            ),
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment(0.1, 0.1),
              child: Container(
                width: 90,
                height: 90,
                color: Colors.red[500],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Desired effect with Container]

---

The other one is by using the custom painter. You just have to fix some positioning in your code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: SplashScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class SplashScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double _width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    // double _height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        width: _width,
        // height: _height,
        child: Center(
          child: Stack(
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              CustomPaint(
                painter: DrawCustomRect(112, 32, 0, 80, 0xFFFF8D8D),
              ),
              CustomPaint(
                painter: DrawCustomRect(96, 16, 0, 96, 0xFFFF5454),
              ),
              CustomPaint(
                painter: DrawCustomRect(80, 0, 0, 112, 0xFFFA2A2A),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DrawCustomRect extends CustomPainter {
  final double _left;
  final double _top;
  final double _right; //width
  final double _bottom; //height
  final int _color;

  DrawCustomRect(this._left, this._top, this._right, this._bottom, this._color);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawRect(
      new Rect.fromLTRB(this._left, this._top, this._right, _bottom),
      new Paint()..color = new Color(_color),
    );
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(DrawCustomRect oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
}
```

[image: Desired effect using custom painter]

Comment: The other one by using the custom painter is what is wanted but there is some positioning issue, what should i do for that?

Comment: You have to manage the top and bottom parameters of the drawRect method as well. I've shown it in the answer above.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this result using Containers inside a Stack:

```
Center(
  child: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 300),
        width: 75,
        height: 100,
        color: Colors.red[300],
      ),
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 150),
        width: 150,
        height: 200,
        color: Colors.red[600],
      ),
      Container(
        width: 225,
        height: 300,
        color: Colors.red[900],
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

And then adjust the sizes and colors based on what you want.

The result:

[image: result]